# Youtube api most viewed for each category

Tags: php

From the Youtube API page (https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html),

Using
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/channelstandardfeeds/BR/most_viewed/-/Music?v=2

It should show the top music channels in BR...but it shows nothing...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do I need an API key?  The link should work without an API key right? https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/channelstandardfeeds/BR/most_viewed/-/Music?v=2

Comment: Then any idea what is the wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this url :
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/BR/most_viewed_Music?v=2

to have the most viewed videos of Music in Brazil

Comment: Sorry, I did not read correctly. I think there is a problem with the feed, because none of countries type works